# How to fix God of War for PC from crashing almost immediately?

Tags: technical-issues, pc, god-of-war-2018, windows-11

I have been trying to run God of War on my PC, but it crashes within one to two minutes of playing.  The "bug splat" from the game says that my GPU may be the issue and suggests that I update my drivers, make sure the GPU isn't overheating, and/or remove any overclocks.  The splat also says that the error reason was my device was removed (the GPU) with reason "device hung".

So far I've done:

- Updated my Nvidia Graphics Driver (using <s>527.56</s> 528.24  currently).
- Removed my GPU overclock.
- Removed CPU and RAM overclocks (turned off D.O.C.P. and reverted RAM speed to default).
- Uninstalled the game and reinstalled (to a faster drive as well).
- Verified game files using Steam (<s>though this didn't seem to work - it got stuck at the 6% mark for a while, but</s> a full reinstall should basically take care of this too).
- Updated my motherboard BIOS.
- Tried running the game with all graphic settings set to low.
- Closed MSI Afterburner (that [worked for me before](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/333606/163757) once on a different game).
- Performed a System File Checker scan using `sfc /scannow`
- Also since posting this question, I've sent my GPU back to the manufacturer via an RMA to which they found nothing wrong (I only did this because I had some other [hardware issues](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62603388#62603388)).

If I check Windows Event Viewer, this is the captured error:

> Faulting application name: GoW.exe, version: 1.0.475.7534, time stamp: 0x628e8031 
> Faulting module name: GoW.exe, version: 1.0.475.7534, time stamp: 0x628e8031 
> Exception code: 0xc0000005 
> Fault offset: 0x0000000000993880 
> Faulting process id: 0x0x2CF8 
> Faulting application start time: 0x0x1D8FA31292E1B4A 
> Faulting application path: M:\Steam\steamapps\common\GodOfWar\GoW.exe 
> Faulting module path: M:\Steam\steamapps\common\GodOfWar\GoW.exe 
> Report Id: b0919472-7bc2-47ec-bf7f-892d06adfae7 
> Faulting package full name: 
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

The only information I've been able to find so far are some Reddit posts that don't have any conclusive solutions.  How can I prevent God of War from crashing?

Hardware Information:

- Gigabyte RTX 3080Ti GPU
- AMD Ryzen 7 5800X CPU
- 16Gb of DDR4 3800 RAM
- ASUS ROG Crosshair VIII Hero Motherboard

---

**January 30th 2023 Update:**

After trying the latest Nvidia driver, I tried again.  The game still crashes.  I decided to look in the installation directory and found the .dmp file of the crash.  I installed [WinDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools#small-windbg-preview-logo-download-windbg-preview) to try and peek into the .dmp file.  After running `!analyze -v`, a bunch of information is displayed.  This is a bit deeper than my knowledge goes on debugging, but I think the relevant information from the tool is the following:

```
EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00007ff9cc1d06bc (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x000000000000006c)
   ExceptionCode: e0000d11
  ExceptionFlags: 00000081
NumberParameters: 3
   Parameter[0]: ffffffff887a0005
   Parameter[1]: 00007ff6244f67e8
   Parameter[2]: 00007ff6244f47e0

PROCESS_NAME:  GoW.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xe0000d11 - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  e0000d11
EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  ffffffff887a0005
EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  00007ff6244f67e8
EXCEPTION_PARAMETER3:  00007ff6244f47e0

STACK_TEXT:  
000000fe`5ee6fcc0 00007ff6`2406b265     : 00000295`0860c710 00000297`851ca010 00000000`00007250 00000000`00000000 : KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x6c
000000fe`5ee6fda0 00007ff6`24054f69     : 00000295`168ea5e0 00007ff6`243bac27 00000295`168ea6a0 00007ff6`2488f9e0 : GoW!agsSetDisplayMode+0x5c89b5
000000fe`5ee6fdf0 00007ff6`243babcd     : 00000000`00000000 00007ff6`2488fca0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : GoW!agsSetDisplayMode+0x5b26b9
000000fe`5ee6fe50 00007ff9`cbe39363     : 00000295`25ddb9a0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : GoW!ffxFsr2GetJitterOffset+0x33979d
000000fe`5ee6fe80 00007ff9`cdd826bd     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ucrtbase!thread_start<unsigned int (__cdecl*)(void *),1>+0x93
000000fe`5ee6feb0 00007ff9`ce74dfb8     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x1d
000000fe`5ee6fee0 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x28

SYMBOL_NAME:  gow+5c89b5
MODULE_NAME: GoW
```

This gave me the idea of attaching a debugger (WinDbg) to the game executable when it's running, so I tried that.  I played the game until it crashed (about 2 minutes in), and this was reported in the tool:

```
(2e00.1f6c): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
00007ff9`ce792af0 cc              int     3

D3D11: Removing Device.
ModLoad: 00007ff9`c4c30000 00007ff9`c4ce0000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\TextShaping.dll
(2e00.4b78): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
GoW!agsSetDisplayMode+0x5b0fd0:
00007ff6`24053880 890c2500000000  mov     dword ptr [0],ecx ds:00000000`00000000=????????
```

I am wondering if whatever `agsSetDisplayMode` is the issue.  Researching this, I found [this page](https://gpuopen-librariesandsdks.github.io/ags/struct_a_g_s_display_settings.html#details), but this seems to be about AMD Graphics , which my computer does not have (Googling this word returns a lot of results mentioning AMD), so I don't know if its correct or not (nor what it even really is). The page says its "The struct to specify the display settings to the driver."

Comment: As of yesterday (in my timezone) Game Ready Driver's newest version is 526.98, perhaps you should try that. I can't say for sure since I don't have GoW on PC, but when I had same (ish) error on Divison 2, completely wiping the GPU driver with Display Driver Uninstaller and performing clean install the GPU driver has solved the issue. Maybe worth a try. ... Completely unrelated, but M drive!? How many drives do you have...?

Comment: @Skye-AT I'll see about trying that.  I have a feeling the GPU driver is completely crashing because when the game crashes, other thing on my computer appear all bugged out and blacked out.  And 5 drives total. I chose random letters :) (C:, D:, H:, L:, M:)

Comment: @Skye-AT I uninstalled my Nvidia driver completely, and then installed 526.98.  The game still crashed unfortunately, darn near instantly too.  I got a different error it seems though captured in Windows Event viewer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLCpX.png

Comment: Hmm. Any chance you've got any other GPU? Not GoW (and not even a game), but I once had same dll was causing exact same issue (fwiw, here's [link (adobe's website)](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/kernel-base-dll-error.html) that explains the issue and how to solve). Not sure if this applies to game, though.

Comment: @Skye-AT I do not have another GPU, not even an integrated one.  I'm starting to run out of options it seems :/

Comment: Well then only thing I can think of is clean installing the OS itself. This would be last resort, if this couldn't fix the problem then I don't know what can fix the problem. It's so much of a work when you just want to play a game..

Comment: Quite a long shot, but are you, by any chance using an Xbox One/Xbox Series X controller on the PC? There used to be an obscure issue (which I was also affected) which would crash the Windows graphics subsystems. I tried doing all the maintenance possible to my GPU but It turns out it was my Xbox controller which needed a firmware update. That fixed all the problems.

Comment: @user1558321 nope, no controller is connected to my pc when I've tried playing the game.

Comment: For future reference, 0xc0000005 is the Windows code for "access violation" (Windows' name for "segementation fault"). In case you ever get this from a game, it means that some program has crashed because of bugs present in that software. So it is unlikely that any amount of tweaking graphic settings will fix it - rather you'll need to find out which program that crashed and then update that one.

Comment: @Amarth wouldn't the program in question be the God of War .exe though? How can I troubleshoot further?

Comment: @TimmyJim I guess if the culprit is actually a driver used by the application, then it's hard to pin-point. You'd have to consider what hardware the program is using - almost certainly the gfx and sound cards, likely the network card or in your case some controller. Since sound and networks cards are most often integrated with the motherboard these days, updating BIOS is a good call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, after many driver updates and trying a ton of other things, the only thing that worked was a costly **hardware replacement**.  I replaced my GPU and the issue is no longer present. The game seems to run fine now.

It's odd because my former GPU worked fine with many other games, but some games (notably Payday 3) would also crash with a similar error of claiming that the DirectX device was lost/disconnected/hung. I've had other games seemingly randomly crash, but I've attributed those random crashes to just that (but there's a very good chance it could have been the GPU in those cases as well).